# easyLocator doesn't load my spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am using the [EasyLocator plugin](https://github.com/SaulBurgos/easyLocator) taking the data from [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z2ATjK8itbVsyqWsNW3xiTzue7TPJiPm1FKiqccf8K0/edit?usp=sharing).

As you can see it has the given format and is shared correctly (it is a copy of the original [demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GsuoK3XyWJoiie1eq0qrd-2DxRVSQ0Ut7DkGI23Gq0s/edit?usp=sharing)).

**I can't understand why my map is not loading the locations.**

You can check my code at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rg9q2aaz/1/), you can uncomment the original spreadsheet line to check it works.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#locatorList').easyLocator({
       spreadsheetId: '1z2ATjK8itbVsyqWsNW3xiTzue7TPJiPm1FKiqccf8K0',
       //spreadsheetId: '1GsuoK3XyWJoiie1eq0qrd-2DxRVSQ0Ut7DkGI23Gq0s',
       useMarkerCluster: true,
       mapType: 'HYBRID'

    });
});
```

Comment: JsFiddle updated, sorry about

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspect your JSFiddle with Chrome Developer tools, and it seem the grid_id is invalid.

[image]

[image]

**Update**

In your code, I changed the spreadSheetId from `1z2ATjK8itbVsyqWsNW3xiTzue7TPJiPm1FKiqccf8K0` to `1GsuoK3XyWJoiie1eq0qrd-2DxRVSQ0Ut7DkGI23Gq0s`,
then it worked.
[image]